# Linux - Recursively go through directories?

Tags: linux, directory

Let's say I am in the directory /home/videos and want to iterate recursively through all of the directories underneath it. If the directory name contains "images" I want to delete the directory and all of its contents. Also, can this be done for files? Let's say in each directory go through every file and check if its name ends with ".mp3" and delete it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "*images*" -type d -exec rm -r {} \;

find . -name "*.mp3" -type f -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

-exec rm -rf {} \; : Delete all files matched by file pattern.

-type f : Only match files and do not include directory names.

-type d : matches only directory names

Comment: Awesome. And this will apply recursively to all directories underneath it?

Comment: @user2523584, yes this will do it recursively

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice tutorial on this. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-how-to-find-and-remove-files/

So you can do something like

```
find /home/videos -type d -name "*images*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

and

```
find /home/videos -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```